# How do GitHub repository work? (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, github, firebase-hosting

So I was installing firestore (ran firebase init) and I linked my GitHub ACCOUNT. I am new to GitHub and I don't really understand what the console is asking me regarding 'Git Hub repository .... format'. Could someone please tell me what to do in this scenario? :)
[image]

It is asking: **For which GitHub repository would you like to set up a GitHub workflow? (format: user/repository)**

I haven't tried to do anything yet since I dont want to do anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This question from the CLI doesn't relate to Firestore, but to Firebase Hosting.

In addition, you should only be getting it you indicate that you want to [deploy to Firebase Hosting when you commit a code change to GitHub](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/github-integration).

Since you don't seem to do that, why are you trying to connect your Firebase project to it? I'd try again, and only select the products that you want to use.